Windows Server 2022 (Azure VM) FTP server. Connects but can't list files in SSL mode
I set up an FTP server within IIS.
The data channel port range is set to 5000-6000 and the "External IP address of firewall" is set to the correct public IP address.
In the Azure firewall for this VM ports 20,21 and 5000-6000 are all open.
I have temporarily disabled the firewall within the Windows VM while I try to get this to work.
If I connect from FileZilla without using SSL then everything is ok.
If I connect with SSL then the below happens (I have changed a username and IP address to xx's)
Status: Connecting to x.x.x.x:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 Microsoft FTP Service
Command:    AUTH TLS
Response:   234 AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation.
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Command:    USER xx
Response:   331 Password required
Command:    PASS ************
Response:   230 User logged in.
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
Command:    PBSZ 0
Response:   200 PBSZ command successful.
Command:    PROT P
Response:   200 PROT command successful.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (x,x,x,x,237,114).
Command:    LIST
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
Status: Disconnected from server

If I connect to the server without using SSL then this issue isn't there, the files get listed plus I can upload files and everything works OK.

IIS tells your client to connect to port 60786. Likely some firewall blocks this, but when in clear-text the firewall has a FTP mode that snoops the port and allows the traffic. TLS blocks the firewall from reading this data, and thus it does not work. Why do you even use FTP? It's an ancient and outdated protocol.

Thanks a lot. I opened up more ports (50,000 to 65,000) and it does work now. Even though in IIS I had configured it to use ports 5000 to 6000. I have set up an SFTP server on Windows before years ago but FTP(S) it easier and it will only be used for a few people/IP addresses.  If you post an answer I can accept it.

https://serverfault.com/q/847663/168875#847872

Installing SFTP on modern Windows OS is very easy. Easier than configuring FTP, as shown by your question...


Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (x,x,x,x,237,114).

IIS tells your client to connect to port 237*256+114=60786.
Likely some firewall blocks this, but when in clear-text the firewall has a FTP mode that snoops the port and allows the traffic. TLS blocks the firewall from reading this data, and thus it does not work.
In general, don't use FTP. It's ancient and outdated.

It would be rather interesting to know why this was downvoted.
